# Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

Tags: haskell, empty-list

Here's my attempt at an expand function:

```
expand :: FileContents -> FileContents -> FileContents  
expand textfile infofile  
  = concat (combine (fst (split separators textfile)) (expand' (snd (split separators textfile))   infofile "")   )  
    where  
      expand' [] _ stack = []  
      expand' (t:ts) info stack  
        |(head t) == '$' = (head (change t info )):expand' ts info stack  
        |otherwise = t: expand' ts info stack  
          where  
            change x y  
              = lookUp x (getKeywordDefs (snd (split ['\n'] y)))
```

When I do:

```
expand "Keywords (e.g. $x, $y, $z...) may appear anwhere, e.g. <$here>." "$x $a\n$y $b\n$z $c\n$here $this-is-one"
```

I get

```
 Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

but I wanted

```
"Keywords (e.g. $a, $b, $c...) may appear anwhere, e.g. <$this-is-one>."
```

Because I should have

```
("Keywords (e.g. $x, $y, $z...) may appear anwhere, e.g. <$here>.",
   "$x $a\n$y $b\n$z $c\n$here $this-is-one")
    ==> "Keywords (e.g. $a, $b, $c...) may appear anwhere, e.g. <$this-is-one>."
```

ADDITION
i defined split myself ,that is:

```
split :: [Char] -> String -> (String, [String])  
split separators ( x : wordsrest)  
      | elem x separators  = (x : listseparators,"" : word : listwords)  
      | otherwise          = (listseparators, ((x : word) : listwords))  
        where  
          (listseparators,    word : listwords) = split separators wordsrest  
split _ _ = ("" , [""])
```

for example 
if I input

```
split " .," "A comma, then some words."
```

then i'll get

```
(" , .",["A","comma","","then","some","words",""])
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior effort and has no question.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse some non-trivial language "by hand". This is probably a bad idea, you should look into parsec or the like. More importantly, if you represented your data as a tree, it would be much easier to do substitutions like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [in the doc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.0.3/docs/Data-Text.html#g:18), `split` does not keep the separators in the chunks it outputs so they may very well be empty.

As a consequence, having `(head t) == '$'` in a guard is unsafe and can lead to exceptions being raised.

Comment: I defined split myself. It has been added to the question as addition.